# Index and search a directory

Tags: search, text, indexing

I have a directory tree containing many text-files. I would like to index the full-text of all these files (ignoring files with certain file-extensions), so that I can quickly search thorugh all of them.

I do not want to index my whole Home directory, or the whole system. I just want to index this particular directory.

The index should update continuously, automatically detecting changes in the files inside.

What tool can I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Except for the requirement "automatically detecting changes in the files", this can be done by GNU [id-utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/manual/). This provides a tool called `mkid` which builds a binary database file called `ID`, that is used by the `lid` query tool, and others.

Id-utils is geared toward programming; it recognizes file types by suffixes, according to a configurable `id-lang.map` file. For each type that it supports, it has a separate scanner so that the tokens from the file are properly handled. There is a fallback scanner for text files, which `mkid` uses, I think, as a fallback for unrecognized file types. I think if you direct `mkid` toward a blank `id-lang.map` file that is blank, it will use the text scanner for everything.

`mkid` indexes trees reasonably quickly, and the queries are lightning fast.

I have integrated it with Vim for source code browsing; it's more convenient than using a separate tool like cscope. With these two settings:

```
:set grepprg=lid\ --regex\ --result=grep\ '$*'\ \\\|\ sort\ -u\ -t\ :\ -k\ 1,1\ -k\ 2,2n
:set grepformat=%f:%l:%m
```

I can use the ID database as the basis for Vim's `:grep` command. E.g. `:grep foo` brings up a navigable list of all the locations where `foo` is found.

The `sort` step in the above `grepprg` definition is required because `lid` puts out matches in funny orders. It's doing hashing internally or something.